# Must declaration of the child class method be compatible with parent class method in PHP?

Tags: php, abstract-class, overloading, extend

**This code is running fine.**

The `ParentClass` is abstract class. I think I can verify that by

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('ParentClass');
$methods = $class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_ABSTRACT);
```

which shows a couple of methods, one of which is named `methodA`.

**Here comes what really baffled me:**

There is a `ChildClass` and it is a concrete class and implements one of the abstract method `methodA`. Using

```
$method = new ReflectionMethod('ChildClass', 'methodA');
var_dump($method->getParameters());
```

I can verify that there are 3 parameters. Since I know the code is working good. I used the same ReflectionMethod to verify the `ParentClass`

```
$method = new ReflectionMethod('ParentClass', 'methodA');
var_dump($method->getParameters());
```

This output an empty array which indicates none parameters, I suppose.

**Why? Sadly, I can't look at the source code of these classes but I have been trying to figure out this without much progress:**

So far, I can only do things like this. The code is in PHP5.4. I really can't figure out how to make an abstract method `_myFunction` without arguments but the concrete child class method with 3 arguments. PHP uses `__call` to overload but this is more of a `extending` issue, I suppose.

```
class A {}

abstract class MyAbstractClass
{   
    //abstract public function _myFunction();// ERROR
    abstract public function _myFunction(A $a, A $b, A $c);
}

class Foobar extends MyAbstractClass
{   
    public function _myFunction(A $a, A $b, A $c = null)
    {   
        echo "abc";
    }
}

$a = new Foobar();
$a->_myFunction(new A(), new A(), new A());
$a->_myFunction(new A(), new A());

//output: abcabc without error
```

Added:

After writing down the question, it helps me to further my test, I think I know why now. The child method has given all 3 arguments a default value.

```
class Foobar extends MyAbstractClass
{   
    public function _myFunction(A $a = null, A $b = null, A $c = null)
    {
        echo "abc";
    }
}
```

This would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php):

> When inheriting from an abstract class, all methods marked abstract in the parent's class declaration must be defined by the child; additionally, these methods must be defined with the same (or a less restricted) visibility.
>
> Furthermore the signatures of the methods must match, i.e. the type hints and the number of required arguments must be the same.

So, the parent class has 0 arguments, the child has 2 *required* ones. That is the problem. But since you changed your code, as you say:

> The child method has given all 3 arguments a default value.

You reduced the number of required arguments in the child class to 0. So it works now.

To recapitate. **This is wrong:**

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass
{   
    abstract public function _myFunction(); // No parameters required
}

class Foobar extends MyAbstractClass
{   
    public function _myFunction(A $a, A $b, A $c = null) // Two parameters required
    {   
        echo "abc";
    }
}
```

**This would also be wrong:**

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass
{   
    abstract public function _myFunction(A $a, A $b, A $c); // Three parameters required
}

class Foobar extends MyAbstractClass
{   
    public function _myFunction(A $a, A $b) // Two parameters required
    {   
        echo "abc";
    }
}
```

**This is okay:**

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass
{   
    abstract public function _myFunction(); // No parameters required
}

class Foobar extends MyAbstractClass
{   
    public function _myFunction(A $a = null, A $b = null, A $c = null) // No parameters required
    {   
        echo "abc";
    }
}
```

**And this is also okay:**

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass
{   
    abstract public function _myFunction(A $a, A $b, A $c);
}

class Foobar extends MyAbstractClass
{   
    public function _myFunction(A $a, A $b, A $c = null)
    {   
        echo "abc";
    }
}
```